# Delete a Unix directory which is inside an Hidden directory using Ant

Tags: unix, ant, hidden

I would really appreciate an answer, been straggling with this issue for a while:

I'm trying to delete a folder "A" which is under an hidden folder called ".b"

the path is root/.b/A   and root/c/d

root is represented by ${user.home}

I'm able to delete "d" using:

```
<delete dir="${user.home}/c/d" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="false" />
```

but cant delete A:

```
    <delete dir="${user.home}" defaultexcludes="no">
        <include name="**/A/*"/>
    </delete>

    <delete dir="${user.home}/.b/A" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="false" />
```

Both ways didn't work. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me...

## Example

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.dummy/A
$ ant

run:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/me/.dummy/A

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

$ find ~/.dummy
/home/me/.dummy
```

Versions

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="HelloWorld" default="run">

  <target name="run">
    <delete dir="${user.home}/.dummy/A" verbose="true"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in Groovy
ex = filedir = c:/user/work

```
ant.delete(includeemptydirs: 'true') {
                fileset(dir: filedir, includes: '**/*', defaultexcludes: "no")
            }
```

In Ant task after adding

> defaultexclude = no

then it will delete hidden files also.
Above ant task delete all content of work folder